# Plugin for Eclipse or Visual Studio that lets me see an overview of the Text similar to Sublime Text

Tags: eclipse, plugins, visual-studio-2013

Are there any plug ins for mentioned IDEs that let me see the whole text file similar to how sublimetext does it? See their [website](http://www.sublimetext.com/), to the right of the text there is a super minimized overview of the entire file. Amazing feature which makes me want to change to it but i rather want an IDE :/ so i hope eclipse or visual studio might have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a plugin called [ProgressiveScroll](https://code.google.com/p/progressive-scroll/) which works on 2010+

It hasn't been updated for a while but seems to work okay in 2013.

Comment: Great, and now when i even know what i easily found it for eclipse as well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And that Visual Studio 2013 already has such a view build in: right clicking scrollbar >  Scroll Bar Options  > map mode

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse now has a built-in feature like this since version 4.9, called Minimap.

You can access it from Window -> Show View. If it's not in the list, click Other... at the bottom, and it's under General.